# Error while using DBContext Generator with Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, generator, edmx, dbcontext

When I use ADO.NET DBContext Generator with Entity Framework 4.1 installed on an EDMX I got the following error:

> Error: this template attempted to load component assembly
>   'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. For more information on this problem
>   and how to enable this template, please see documentation on
>   Customizing Project Templates.

I'm using VS2010 with SP1, Entity Framework 4.1 from NuGet, .net 4 Class Library

Am I missing something?

I have "Microsoft Entity Framework June 2011 CTP" installed and when I select it from the project target frameworks then the template "DBContext Generator" works. IS that mean I have to uninstall the CTP to get it working with normal .net framework 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I has to re-install Entity framework to get it work using:

```
ADONETEntityFrameworkTools_enu.msi USING_EXUIH=1 /log "dd_ADONETEntityFrameworkTools_enu_MSI.txt"
```

Reference: [Deploying Visual Studio Components Individually](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee225240.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting this and the info.  For those that run into this after installing the EF 4.2 June CTP:

1. Uninstall the SQL Server Data Tools June CTP package
2. Then follow AMgdy's advice above

ADONETEntityFrameworkTools_enu.msi USING_EXUIH=1 /log "dd_ADONETEntityFrameworkTools_enu_MSI.txt"